# Connect MongoDB server that is deployed on docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm new to MongoDB.

My manager says that he has deployed MongoDB on Docker for testing purposes. He shared the server name and it is running on 27017 port.

He told me that I do not need to install Docker or MongoDB on my VDI, I just need to connect to the MongoDB server from client.

Now, I'm totally clueless on how to do that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you can access the said mongodb at 27017 port. You can use telnet or such similar commands. If the connection is successful you can use the mongodb_host and port directly in your script.

Comment: Should I used the telnet command from command prompt?

Comment: yes; do a simple google search for how to do `telnet` in your operating system; it will guide you.

Comment: It is a client VDI and I do not have the privileges to use telnet

Comment: Can you install mongodb clients like robomongo GUI tool? You can try connecting it from there.

Comment: Downloaded MongoDB Compass, need to wait for the ITSecurity guys to give me privilege to access the tool